Data filtering issue on powerbI
So, when we're filtering  all data from day, month, and year (selecting all function).
Now, 5 out of 6 visuals are filtering data but 1 isn't doing that.
Below attached is the[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/TDykjxJj.jpg) query used for filtering and visuals screenshot is attached.
almost everything like changing querys MTD Sales = CALCULATE([Sales], DATESMTD(DATEADD(ActualDate[Date], -1, DAY)))

Does the visual work when a month/year is selected? Could the issue be that you have no data for the end of your 'ActualDate" table?

Correct your data model first, then check tables for Null.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

check if the visual-interaction turned off.
change how visuals interact in a Power BI Report
